# Checking if a SPUser is in an SPGroup

Tags: development, permissions

I'm seeing some inconsistency in the code below determining if a SPUser is part of an SPGroup.  I thought it might be that the group membership needs to refresh but I've recycled services and still the check is not performing correctly.  Am I missing something here?

```
               //Executive Approved
               if ((properties.AfterProperties["Status"] + "") == "Executive Approved")
               {
                   var approverGroup = properties.ListTitle == "Infrastructure Change Requests" ? "Infrastructure Request Executive Approvers" : "Application Request Executive Approvers";

                   try
                   {
                       if (properties.OpenWeb().Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId).Groups[approverGroup] !=
                           null)    
                       {
                           properties.Cancel = false;
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       properties.Cancel = true;
                       properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                       properties.ErrorMessage = "Update not allowed.  Only " + approverGroup + " can make this approval." + " [" + ex.Message + "]";
                   }
               }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this with an else statement and you got an array index out of bounds error?

Comment: I have not.  The catch should capture that though correct?  When it fails I do not get an index out of bounds error.  The Groups[] takes an int as an id but it also takes a string as a key.

Comment: I don't know what the exact error would be, but it's possible that it doesn't actually throw an error and it's processing it even thought the person isn't in that group. If you haven't tried putting the else statement in there, I'd give that a shot.

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts.  This one has me stumped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check the proper collection.  I was checking the SPWeb.Groups property but the group was not in this collection.  I updated the code to elevate and then check the SPWeb.SiteGroups collection and this solved the problem.

```
               SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
                        {
                            //Manager Approved 
                            if ((properties.AfterProperties["Status"] + "") == "Manager Approved")
                            {
                                var approverGroup = properties.ListTitle == "Infrastructure Change Requests" ? "Infrastructure Request Manager Approvers" : "Application Request Manager Approvers";

                                try
                                {
                                    SPUser user = web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);
                                    SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups[approverGroup];

                                    if (!user.InGroup(group))
                                    {
                                        properties.Cancel = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    properties.Cancel = true;
                                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                                    properties.ErrorMessage = "Update not allowed.  Only " + approverGroup + " can make this approval." + " [" + ex.Message + "]";
                                }
                            }
                       }
                  });
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the following approach to determine whether user belongs to a specific group or not:

```
public static class SPUserExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUserInGroup(this SPUser user,string groupName)
    {
        return user.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(groupName));
    }
}
```

Then you could replace the checking:

```
if (properties.OpenWeb().Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId).Groups[approverGroup] !=null)    
{
    //...
}
```

with this one:

```
if (properties.OpenWeb().Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId).IsUserInGroup(approverGroup))    
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private Boolean IsUserInGroup(SPGroup oGroupToTestFor,String sUserLoginName)
{   
    Boolean bUserIsInGroup = false;
    try
    {
        SPUser x = oGroupToTestFor.Users[sUserLoginName];
        bUserIsInGroup = true;
    }
    catch (SPException)
    {
        bUserIsInGroup = false;
    }
    return bUserIsInGroup;

}

IsUserInGroup(Group, context.User.Identity.Name);
```

You need to take care of few things

Make sure the current user has read membership permission on the group.

Comment: Good thought, the groups are set up so that members can view the membership though.