# Check user in group (C#)

Tags: development, permissions, 2016, groups

How to check in C# if the current user is in a group or not? Thanks for help.

```
 using (SPSite SPsite = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/test"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = SPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                    SPGroupCollection groups = user.Groups;

                    foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
                    {
                        string groupName = group.Name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

CSOM not need.

Comment: Do you want check the user permission for particular group??

Comment: Not necessary, only if he is in the group or not.

Comment: You want this solution in SSOM and not in CSOM, right??

Comment: Check the answers given in [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121215/checking-if-a-spuser-is-in-an-spgroup) or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/65066c08-9924-4935-9bba-f715b75d3fac/how-to-check-if-user-exists-in-a-particular-sharepoint-group-or-not-programatically) and let me know which one of this works for you.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh is working this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/65066c08-9924-4935-9bba-f715b75d3fac/how-to-check-if-user-exists-in-a-particular-sharepoint-group-or-not-programatically

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked for you. please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve this using SSOM, I will recommend you trying the solutions given in below links:

1. [How to check if user exists in a particular SharePoint group or not programatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/65066c08-9924-4935-9bba-f715b75d3fac/how-to-check-if-user-exists-in-a-particular-sharepoint-group-or-not-programatically)
2. [Checking if a SPUser is in an SPGroup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121215/checking-if-a-spuser-is-in-an-spgroup)

**Code for reference**:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName = "PERSEUS\\dmitry.kaloshin";
            string groupName = "Home Members";
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://perseus"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(userName);
                    if (user.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(groupName)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User " + userName + " is a member of group " + groupName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User " + userName + " is NOT a member of group " + groupName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```